# Why $\int _0 ^{\alpha\pi} \sin x \cos x dx$ is $0$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, orthogonality

$$\int _0 ^{\alpha \pi} \sin x \cos x dx = 0$$
I saw this formula in a book and I'm wondering for what values of alpha ($\alpha$) in the upper limit of integral is the integral $0$?
(My guess is that it has something to do with orthogonal functions)
Edit : I'm more interested to know why this integral is zero rather than the values of alpha

Comment: Math equations must be enclosed in `$ ... $`

Comment: Note that the derivative of $\sin^2(x)$ is $2 \sin(x) \cos(x)$, so you can easily compute that integral explicitly.

Comment: This is correct for integers $\alpha$, but no other values.  Why not use Martin's hint and prove this yourself?

Comment: Got it now sin nπ is zero for all integers thanks sir

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\int \sin x\cos x\; \mathrm d x = \frac{1}{2}\sin^2 x + C$$
Hence,
$$2 \int_0^{\alpha \pi} \sin x\cos x\; \mathrm d x = \sin^2(\alpha \pi) = 0$$
This is true when $\alpha \in \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative Solution:
$\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$

Thus the given integral has a $\sin$ curve with Double Period.
We know $\sin$ curve has $0$ area over a Period $[0,2\pi]$ or over every Period $[0,2\pi n]$ ...
... which means $2 \pi \alpha$ should be $2 \pi n$ ...
... which means $\alpha$ is some Integer.

When $\alpha$ is some other Number, the Integral is Strictly Non-Zero or rather Positive.

Comment: Please use `$\sin$` instead of `$sin$`. Otherwise very good point that $\alpha$ has to be an integer